# Correct text positioning in libGDX

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx

I have a problem with the proper scaling and setting of the text in libGDX. I use two screens: one for the game menu and the other for gameplay. In the menu, each text is entered in a Label and placed in a table in Stage. In the play screen, the text should be placed freely, because it does not have a fixed position: it follows the player displaying his nickname. The very important thing is that I am using Box2d, therefore the whole game world is scaled (1/100).

Unfortunately, I ran into a problem with the play screen. The text I want to display is not positioned properly. First of all, it is oversized (probably a problem with the lack of proper use of the scale here), and secondly, it does not want to accept floating-point values. It always aligns relative to the integer values "to the grid" and you can see very large jumps through the changed scale.

This is what the same font looks like in the menu:

[image]

And in the case of the play screen (a piece of black spot is the beginning of the letter "N" :P):

[image]

This is how I create a BitmapFont object:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter normalFontParameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
normalFontParameter.color = Color.WHITE;
normalFontParameter.borderWidth = 3f;
normalFontParameter.borderColor = Color.BLACK;
normalFontParameter.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
normalFontParameter.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
normalFontParameter.size = 100;
normalFont = fontGenerator.generateFont(normalFontParameter);
```

This is the code from the menu screen:

```
Label.LabelStyle labelNormalStyle = new Label.LabelStyle(normalFont, Color.WHITE);
Label nicknameLabel = new Label("Nickname", labelNormalStyle);
table.add(nicknameLabel);
```

And this is the code from the play screen:

```
normalFont.draw(batch, "Nickname", getX(), getY());
```

How to properly position this font? I will be grateful for help.

Comment: Do you still need an answer or did you figure it out already?

Comment: I haven't found a specific solution that works for me. I only found out and I am sure that my mistake is that the UI elements are not scaling correctly. I'm trying to display a font in the game, but the game world has a different scale than the Stage (UI).

Comment: You’re displaying the text in the game’s camera, not the Stage camera? Half of your problem is that you haven’t called `setUseIntegerPositions(false)`. The default is true because often (historically) text is all drawn in a UI layer that uses a ScreenViewport with pixel perfect fonts in nearest filtering, so they look crisp with low performance hit. Nowadays, I think that’s overkill and you should use a mipmapped font with trilinear filtering so you don’t have to worry about providing fonts for every possible screen size.

Comment: But if you’re generating fonts at runtime, I suppose it makes more sense to generate them pixel perfect for the current screen. You might consider adding a third camera/viewport in between game and Stage that is the same dimensions as the screen so you can crisply display your generated font pixel perfect. Then integer positions would be appropriate and you won’t have to scale the fonts. You would just need to write a function to convert game world coordinates to screen coordinates so you know where to put the text in the text layer.